# Could a pilot be in violation of an FAA rule for the use of an EFB solely as an aid to situational awareness?

Tags: faa-regulations, efb

Are there potential situations in which use of an EFB *even as a supplement for situational awareness only* would be considered a violation of a rule?

I understand that some operators do not have approval to use EFBs, and they are required to utilize paper charts.  Does that normally preclude the use of an EFB for supplementation as long as all requirements are otherwise met by onboard paper products?

I suppose one could say this is unlikely to happen for the sole reason that it's hard to prove what is being used onboard in-flight, and my question is more to the point of *whether or not the use is actually allowed* as long as it's only a supplementation.

Answer (score 4):

Back in 2017 the FAA allowed own-ship display on EFBs in-flight:

> [AC120-76D](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/1032166) replaces the -C version issued in 2014, which for commercial operators specifically prohibited use of geo-referencing or own-ship position display while using moving-map features in the air. Use of geo-referencing on the ground was previously considered acceptable by the agency.
>
> — FAA To Allow Own-ship Display on EFB Apps. [ainonline.com](https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/air-transport/2017-11-15/faa-allow-own-ship-display-efb-apps). November 15, 2017.

So, it used to be an issue, but not anymore.

---

Here's what it looks like aboard an Airbus A350 (taken in 2021):

> [image]
> Source: [justplanes.com](https://shop.justplanes.com/Cockpit-NEW-Series/c/1364/Air-Caraibes-A350-1000/p/164362) (combined and annotated two images)